# Data Pipeline performance

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

If we have 10TB data flowing (may be 3 days in a week) and some times the data received is only 100 MB(4 days in a week). What are the possible ways to handle such inconsistent data in spark data pipeline efficiently ?

Comment: Hi! This is a generic doubt than a code issue and therefore will mostly attract opinion based answers. I suggest you to read [mcve] and try to highlight any issues you are facing while trying to run the job. As for your question, you can use dynamic executor allocation with the minimum starting number as 5, I suppose. Then, your application will scale and request for more executors as long as your code is aptly written to handle that amount of data.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.